# How to add a multi-line dynamic listview with alternate colors?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, dynamic

I want to add a list-view dynamically where i can put heading in line 1 and the corresponding text in line 2.
I have used a simple adapter to put values in listview.

This is my java activity:

```
 String serverResponse = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_holidays);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy ourPolicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(ourPolicy);

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
    ((TextView)actionbar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.mytext)).setText("Holidays");


    HttpResponseCache response = null;
    try {
        // Create http client object to send request to server
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Create URL string
        String URL = "http://ran.mantraeducation.in/push.aspx?user=ASA103101&pass=20041129&request=notice&MSelect=4";
        // Create Request to server and get response
        HttpGet httpget= new HttpGet();
        httpget.setURI(new URI(URL));
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        serverResponse = client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

        initList();
         ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, noticeList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"notice"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);


    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

List<Map<String,String>> noticeList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
private void initList(){
    try{
        JSONArray jarray= new JSONArray(serverResponse);
        for(int i=0; i<jarray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject jo = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String description = jo.getString("Description");
            String noticeDate = jo.getString("NoticeDate");
            String outPut = noticeDate + ":  " +description;
            noticeList.add(createNotice("notice", outPut));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private HashMap<String, String>createNotice(String name,String number){
    HashMap<String, String> noticeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    noticeNameNo.put(name, number);
    return noticeNameNo;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent dashboardIntent = new Intent(HolidaysActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
    startActivity(dashboardIntent);
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

This is my XML File:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:dividerHeight="8px"/>
```

Comment: You should use a custom adapter. For this, you need to create a xml file for the row and extend some Adapter class, like ArrayAdapter. Right now I cant put a code sample, but I could write a more detailed answer later.

Answer (score 0):

[with this custom listview you can have first line as header and second line as text](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)

[However I would recommend using recyclerview because it is more efficient and used frequently now](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/)